# Color ts files texts in vs code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

text colorization works everywhere except in .ts extension files in my vs code. I tried several themes but nothing worked!
You have an idea ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by adding following settings :

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.ts": "javascript"
}
```

Ref: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the file type explicitly?

1. Click the "File Type" button in the bottom bar
   [image: Click the "File Type" button in the bottom bar]
2. Type `typescript` and choose the first option
   [image: Type "typescript" and choose the first option]

For video tutorial, you could [watch this tutorial in YouTube](https://youtu.be/4b4ByDkkmjY). :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you use an extension or something else to find Typescript when you tape it on the searchbar ? I got nothing when I search it

Comment: Did you try to reinstall Visual Studio Code? TypeScript support is built-in in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: thanks. I reinstalled vs code but it still doesn't work. I decided to choose Javescript's config instead. It works too, thank you for your help